# Bind to NG Plugin event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this plugin in my project. https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider

Basically, the user drags the slider and I try to capture the input based on the following on my client side:

```
<rzslider rz-slider-floor="0" rz-slider-ceil="100" rz-slider-model="slider" rz-slider-translate="translate">
</rzslider>
```

So $scope.slider holds the value. However, I want to know when the user has stopped dragging the slider so that I know and update the value accordingly in my database.

There's a slideEnded event according to the author but since I'm new to NG, I would really like some help on how to bind to this event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add below function in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('slideEnded', function () {

      console.log("slideEnded Event Fired")
      // You can get slider selected value to your model which you have used in your slider

});
```

rzslider.js emits an event 'slideEnded' when user stop sliding and leave the mouse click.. we just need to catch that event in our controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method in your html:

```
<rzslider
        id="rz-slider"
        rz-slider-floor="0"
        rz-slider-ceil="periodMax"
        rz-slider-model="periodSlider"
        rz-slider-translate="periodTranslate"
        rz-slider-tpl-url="rzSliderTpl.html"
        rz-slider-on-end="onSliderEnd()"
        rz-slider-on-change="onSliderChange()"
        rz-slider-present-only="false"
        ></rzslider>
```

Then in your controller:

```
   $scope.onSliderChange = function(){}
   $scope.onSliderEnd = function(){}
```